# What is the difference between do, tiel, tial, tiom, and sekve?

Tags: word-difference

Can someone tell me the difference between these words?They all can translate as “ so” in English. I’ve also seen do, tiel, and tial translated as “therefore”. Please also provide sentence examples Thanks.

Comment: **So** the problem is that there are **so** many meanings of the word *so* in English, **so** the translations from Esperanto end up appearing **so** similar, when in fact they are different meanings.

Answer (score 5):

```
Reason    kial = why            tial = therefore, so, for that reason
Manner    kiel = how            tiel = so, in that way
Quantity  kiom = how much/many  tiom = that much

Following                       sekve = so, as a consequence
```

Answer (score 2):

The so called [table words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto_vocabulary#Table_of_correlatives) (correlatives) have a very specific meaning. The table words starting with **ti-** correspond to the question words starting with **ki-**.

While the english word **so** is very unspecific, the table words represent the basic categories for anything you can think about:

- quality
- reason
- time
- place
- manner
- association
- object
- amount
- individual

The english word **so** can only be understood in context.

> **Tial** means exactly **for that reason** and nothing else.
>
> **Tiel** means exactly **in that manner** and nothing else.
>
> **Tiom** means exactly **that amount** and nothing else.

I don't see, how **tiom** could translate to **so** rather than to **so much** (but I am not a native English speaker).

The translation of **sekve** is best considered **consequently**.