# How does «do» differ from the other words for “so”?

Tags: adverbs, correlatives

In [What is the difference between do, tiel, tial, tiom, and sekve?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/5163/1990) the answers address the differences between all the title’s words—except for *do.*

I just saw a Duolingo sentence,

> Mi ne ankoraŭ aliĝis, **do** mi ne estas aliĝinto.

and Duolingo didn’t accept *tial* (for that reason) as a substitute for *do,* and I can’t find a resource that explains. (PIV’s entries on [*do*](https://vortaro.net/#do) and [*tial*](https://vortaro.net/#tial) make it seem like *tial/do* should frequently be substitutable.)

Answer (score 2):

*'Do'* and *'tial'* *are* often substitutable for each other, but swapping them *does* subtly change the meaning in most cases.

*'Do'* is about **conclusions**, often logical or even just linguistic. (And, by extension, for follow-up questions.)

*'Tial'* is about **causes** (including motivations).

So use *'tial'* where you're relating two or more **events** that each have some (often unstated or maybe even unknown) point in time and that make up causal chains.

E.g.,

> 1. I wasn't sure, I'd like the event.
> 2. Therefore, I didn't sign up.

> Mi ne certis, ĉu mi ŝatus la eventon.
>   **Tial** me ne aliĝis.

or

> Mi ne certis, ĉu mi ŝatus la eventon,
>   **tial** me ne aliĝis.

I.e., not being sure **caused** me to not sign up.

With *'do'* we can relate **statements**, some of which (or whose relation) might exist outside of time.

E.g.,

> 1. I didn't sign up yet.
> 2. Thus [by definition], I'm not a sign-up-ee (=someone who has signed up, a registrant).

> Mi ne ankoraŭ aliĝis.
>   **Do** mi ne estas aliĝinto.

or

> Mi ne ankoraŭ aliĝis,
>   **do** mi ne estas aliĝinto.

I.e., from the fact that I didn't sign up, I can logically (or here even just linguistically) **conclude** that I'm not someone who has signed up. (Duh.)

Even though me not signing up and me not being a registrant are events or states that both could be assigned to some point in time, their logical relation exists completely outside of time. It's not that I first not signed up, and that *then caused* me to not be someone who's signed up. Thus, using *'tial'* here, while maybe not completely wrong, would at least feel overly heavy and rather strange.

This difference is difficult to grasp, as many languages, including English, while having plenty of different words for these two meanings, use them rather indistinctly for both of these purposes (and some of them, like "so" for even many more meanings than just these two):

- because of that
- therefore
- so
- for that reason
- thus
- thusly

And even in Esperanto, if you turn the relation around, it becomes less clear what word(s) should be used.

> Because I wasn't sure that I'd like the event, I didn't sign up.

> **Ĉar** mi ne certis, ĉu mi ŝatus la eventon, mi ne aliĝis.

but also

> As I didn't sign up yet, I'm not a registrant.

> **Ĉar** mi ne ankoraŭ aliĝis, mi ne estas aliĝinto.

Comment: _Pro ke mi ne certis, ĉu mi ŝatus la eventon, mi ne aliĝis._ estas vere stranga frazo, ĉu vi celis _pro TIO ke ..._?

Comment: Hmm ... I thought I heard it with just "pro ke", but you're right that "pro tio(,) ke" would make more sense. I'll just remove it from the answer.